# NSUserDefaults - Xamarin

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm just trying to save / restore a couple doubles.  What I'm seeing is that it works while attached to debugger, but after 15 minutes of the app being closed - relaunch app and it restores "-180" for both doubles.

Does this look right?  Or you think I'm saving "-180" somehow?

This is with device not simulator.  i'm using `Map.DidUpdateUserLocation` which gives `MKUserLocationEventArgs`.
Somehow it gives -180,-180 for position.  Possible Xamarin bug?

```
    private CLLocationCoordinate2D GetLastLocation()
    {
        var user = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

        double lat = user.DoubleForKey ("LastPositionLat");
        double lng = user.DoubleForKey ("LastPositionLng");

        var location = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (lat, lng);
        return location;
    }

    private void SaveLastLocation(CLLocationCoordinate2D coord)
    {
        var user = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
        user.SetDouble (coord.Latitude, "LastPositionLat");
        user.SetDouble (coord.Longitude, "LastPositionLng");
        user.Synchronize ();
    }
```

Comment: Where are u calling `SaveLastLocation()` method?

Answer (score 4):

This question is quite old, but it jumped at me for one reason, we've seen *very* strange behavior storing NSUserDefaults.StandardUserdefaults in a local variable and then repeatedly accessing it.

Something in the Xamarin.iOS binding (at least for the MonoTouch, i.e. non-unified API) is pretty broken there, likely a GC issue where the object looses it's native peer. We have this in our codebase:

```
    // it appears that capturing an instance of NSUserDefaults.StandardUserdefaults in a variable does not work in every case
    // we have observed a voodoo bug when reading a written value from such an instance would fail (as I said, voodoo!)
    // thus, we directly access standard user defaults here always via the lambda
```

Comment: Ha interesting , I can't confirm whether this is the fix anymore. I quit the side project that I was working on with this.  If someone could confirm then I'll mark as answer

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use the nuget package for handling (PCL) Settings that you can find on github [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings) or install through nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/)

I've used this library on many projects in the past, and never presents me with any strange values. Please note that if you *do* see '-180' appear all over again, it means that something, somewhere in your code is writing that value.

Answer (score 0):

-180 definitely seems suspicious since it is not 0 or MAX double and seemingly related to coordinates. Perhaps you are grabbing the user's location before the location manager has time to locate them. You might check that the reading the location manager gives you is not older than ~15 seconds. It typically gives you the last location lock while it is getting the latest. -180 might be what the simulator gives you as 'last known location'.

I don't know monotouch but it looks like you are calling the correct methods.

Comment: This is with device not simulator though.  i'm using Map.DidUpdateUserLocation which gives MKUserLocationEventArgs.  Somehow it gives -180,-180 for position.  Xamarin bug?

Answer (score 0):

I find out that application Id in simulator will be changed after you relaunch it from xamarin studio. Probably it breaks NSUserDefaults storage, to check it you can relaunch application by touching app icon on simulator.

Comment: Does it do it on device also?

Comment: not sure, you can check it, path to the applications resources in runtime, contain application ID, and it will be different at every launch.

Comment: Hard to believe.  This would then break all storage and no one could debug.  My problem outlined is on device and not connected to debugger.